# R error in lemmatizzation a corpus of document with wordnet

Tags: r, wordnet, lemmatization

i'm trying to lemmatizzate a corpus of document in R with wordnet library. This is the code:

```
corpus.documents <- Corpus(VectorSource(vector.documents))
corpus.documents <- tm_map(corpus.documents removePunctuation)

library(wordnet)
lapply(corpus.documents,function(x){
  x.filter <- getTermFilter("ContainsFilter", x, TRUE)
  terms <- getIndexTerms("NOUN", 1, x.filter)
  sapply(terms, getLemma)
})
```

but when running this. I have this error:

```
Errore in .jnew(paste("com.nexagis.jawbone.filter", type, sep = "."), word,  :
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: <init>
```

and those are stack calls:

```
5 stop(structure(list(message = "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: <init>", 
call = .jnew(paste("com.nexagis.jawbone.filter", type, sep = "."), 
    word, ignoreCase), jobj = <S4 object of class structure("jobjRef", package 
="rJava")>), .Names = c("message", 
"call", "jobj"), class = c("NoSuchMethodError", "IncompatibleClassChangeError",  ... 
4 .jnew(paste("com.nexagis.jawbone.filter", type, sep = "."), word, 
ignoreCase) 
3 getTermFilter("ContainsFilter", x, TRUE) 
2 FUN(X[[1L]], ...) 
1 lapply(corpus.documents, function(x) {
x.filter <- getTermFilter("ContainsFilter", x, TRUE)
terms <- getIndexTerms("NOUN", 1, x.filter)
sapply(terms, getLemma) ...
```

what's wrong?

Comment: what exactly is `getLemma`? Cant see it in your code above

Comment: It's part of package `wordnet`

Comment: @ntrax - I think `getTermFilter(...,x)` expects a character argument. You are passing a `TextDocument` object. Try `getTermFilter("ContainsFilter", as.character(x), TRUE)`. When I try this (on a simple document - *you didn't provide any data!!!*), that function works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this does not address your use of `wordnet`, but does provide an option for lemmatizing that might work for you (and is better, IMO...). This uses the MorphAdorner API developed at Northwestern University. You can find detailed documentation [here](http://morphadorner.northwestern.edu/server/). In the code below I'm using their [Adorner for Plain Text API](http://morphadorner.northwestern.edu/server/partofspeechtaggerservice/).

```
# MorphAdorner (Northwestern University) web service
adorn <- function(text) {
  require(httr)
  require(XML)
  url <- "http://devadorner.northwestern.edu/maserver/partofspeechtagger"
  response <- GET(url,query=list(text=text, media="xml", 
                                 xmlOutputType="outputPlainXML",
                                 corpusConfig="ncf", # Nineteenth Century Fiction
                                 includeInputText="false", outputReg="true"))
  doc <- content(response,type="text/xml")
  words <- doc["//adornedWord"]
  xmlToDataFrame(doc,nodes=words)
}

library(tm)
vector.documents <- c("Here is some text.", 
                      "This might possibly be some additional text, but then again, maybe not...",
                      "This is an abstruse grammatical construction having as it's sole intention the demonstration of MorhAdorner's capability.")
corpus.documents <- Corpus(VectorSource(vector.documents))
lapply(corpus.documents,function(x) adorn(as.character(x)))
# [[1]]
#   token spelling standardSpelling lemmata partsOfSpeech
# 1  Here     Here             Here    here            av
# 2    is       is               is      be           vbz
# 3  some     some             some    some             d
# 4  text     text             text    text            n1
# 5     .        .                .       .             .
# ...
```

I'm just showing the lemmatization of the first "document". `partsOfSpeech` follows the NUPOS convention.

Comment: first of all, many many thanks to everyone for the help! The MorphAdorner web service seems to be very intresting! thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

This answers your question, but does not really solve your problem. There is another solution above (different answer) that attempts to provide a solution.

There are several issues with the way you are using the `wordnet` package, described below, but the bottom line is that even after addressing these, I could not get `wordnet` to produce anything but gibberish.

First: You can't just install the `wordnet` package in R, you have to install Wordnet on your computer, or at least download the dictionaries. Then, before you use the package, you need to run `initDict("path to wordnet dictionaries")`.

Second: It looks like `getTermFilter(...)` expects a character argument for `x`. The way you have it set up, you are passing an object of type `PlainTextDocument`. So you need to use `as.character(x)` to convert that to it's contained text, or you get the java error in your question.

Third: It looks like `getTermFilter(...)` expects single words (or phrases). For instance, if you pass "This is a phrase" to `getTermFilter(...)` it will look up "This is a phrase" in the dictionary. It will not find it of course, so `getIndexTerms(...)` returns `NULL` and `getLemma(...)` fails... So you have to parse the text of your `PlainTextDocument` into words first.

Finally, I'm not sure it's a good idea to remove punctuation. For instance "it's" will be converted to "its" but these are different words with different meanings, and they lemmatize differently.

Rolling all this up:

```
library(tm)
vector.documents <- c("This is a line of text.", "This is another one.")
corpus.documents <- Corpus(VectorSource(vector.documents))
corpus.documents <- tm_map(corpus.documents, removePunctuation)

library(wordnet)
initDict("C:/Program Files (x86)/WordNet/2.1/dict")
lapply(corpus.documents,function(x){
  sapply(unlist(strsplit(as.character(x),"[[:space:]]+")), function(word) {
    x.filter <- getTermFilter("StartsWithFilter", word, TRUE)
    terms    <- getIndexTerms("NOUN",1,x.filter)
    if(!is.null(terms)) sapply(terms,getLemma)
  })
})
# [[1]]
#                 This                   is                    a                 line                   of                 text 
#            "thistle"              "isaac"                  "a"               "line" "off-axis reflector"               "text"
```

As you can see, the output is still gibberish. "This" is lemmatized as "thistle" and so on. It may be that I have the dictionaries configured improperly, so you might have better luck. If you are committed to `wordnet`, for some reason, I suggest you contact the package authors.